# Forwarding all traffic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, raspberry-pi, port-forwarding

There is such a scheme:
[image]

1. The operating system ubuntu server 22.04 is installed on Raspberry Pi4.
2. Through the main network interface, Rpi is connected to the home router and has access to the Internet.
3. Also, a USB-to-Ethernet adapter is connected to the Rpi, and the client is connected through this adapter.

Could you tell me please, how can I configure the routing table so that the client also has internet access?

I understand that you can configure Rpi as an additional NAT or link interfaces to a bridge.

Regarding the network setup:
The main `Eth0 interface` on the `Rpi` receives an IP address via `DHCP` from the home router. IP address: 192.168.1.150, mask: 255.255.255.0, gateway: 192.168.1.1 and DNS server: 192.168.1.1.

As for the usb-adapter, nothing has been configured there yet, as I understand it, this interface (it is defined as enx00e04c360a7f) needs to be assigned an IP address manually, but unfortunately, I still don’t understand how to do this, and what I need to specify parameters. Accordingly, the client connected to this interface must specify the IP - the subnet address of the interface, and the gateway will be the IP address of the interface. Apparently, if you assign an IP address of 192.168.2.1 to the interface, then on the client side the settings will be as follows: IP: 192.168.2.2, mask / 24, gateway 192.168.2.1 and, probably, DNS should also be 192.168.2.1 for the Internet to work fully move.

Comment: This depends on what type of internet access you want to have on the client. Do you just want "browsing"? Or do you want to have unlimited access for all applications? In the first case, it would be sufficient to install a web-proxy on the *Raspi*, in the latter case you would need to enable ip-forwarding on the *Raspi* and set the USB Ip-Address as default gateway on the client. Be aware that a firewall configuration would be neccessary on the *Raspi* in any case.

Comment: Hey Alex! This is very hard to answer without knowing about your intended subnet and addressing setups. Could you label each network interface, to which that is applicable, with an (exemplary) IP address **and** subnet? This would answer a lot of questions on how you need routing to be set up very quickly :)

Comment: @gerhardd. Yes, I'm interested in unlimited access to everything.

Comment: @MarcusMüller. Thanks for the comment, I'll add the information to my question now.

Comment: @AlexRebell is it correct that you can configure a routing table entry on the router between your 192.168.1.0/24 networ and WAN? (If that's the case, gerhard isn't quite right: you only need to set up routing on the RPi, and don't really need to concern yourself with firewall setup; and I'd add that setting up a proxy would probably be more complex these days than a NAT solution, but that's a subjective statement by me)

Comment: Ok so i think we have these building blocks: 1) enable ip-forwarding 2) enable NAT on outgoing interface: https://pastebin.com/SBCKMJAe. That should give you the ability to ping outside hosts from the client, when configuring the client manually. What i do not know is how USB-to-ETH is set up. This depends on what you use for networkconfiguration (NetworManager ...). Could you add that information? After configuring the usb-to-eth interface, you may also add `dnsmasq` on the RASPI so that it forwards DHCP from and to the router. EDIT: in the linked script, it should always be 'echo "1"'.

Comment: @gerhardd. So, I did according to your instructions, what happened: 
uncommented the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`, did not touch the line with `version 6`, then executed `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, then `modprobe ip_tables` and `modprobe ip_conntrack`, and after `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`. really `sudo iptables -L` shows me everything is empty, is it supposed to be?

Comment: @gerhardd.  to set up the `usb adapter network` i used the command: `sudo ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev enx00e04c360a7f` then `sudo ip link set dev enx00e04c360a7f down` and `sudo ip link set dev enx00e04c360a7f up`

Comment: @gerhardd. on the client, which is connected via usb adapter, configured the network: IP-192.168.2.2, mask 24, gateway 192.168.2.1. Now my home router is accessible from the client at 192.168.1.1 - Excellent! It remains only to configure so that the client has access to the Internet.

Comment: According to information on the internet, Ubuntu 22.04 uses `Netplan` for configuration of the network devices. Please use this tutorial to set up a netplan file which configures your usb-adapter statically, so that it comes up automatically: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-network-configuration. Then we look after the rest.

Comment: @gerhardd. I set up the network via `Netplan`

Comment: Great. So you can reach the Raspi directly from the client, and packets from the client to the internet are sent over it? Then you should try the following: 1) Start `tcpdump -i eth0 -v -s0 -X icmp` on the Raspi, and ping an external site from the client. Then paste the output of the tcpdump here.

Comment: on the `client`, I configured the `network adapter` as follows: IP `192.168.2.10`, mask `24`, Gateway `192.168.2.1` (the IP address of the usb adapter on the RPi), dns server `192.168.1.1` (my home router) and there is an Internet on the client, I can use all resources without restriction. command output `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -v -s0 -X icmp` on Rpi https://pastebin.com/MH0SsgsP (this is only a part, in general there is a lot of such information). if such settings are on the client, then we can assume that everything was configured correctly?

Comment: It surely looks like. Do you want to create a network for more than one client on the 192.168.2.0/24 side? Then we would have to additionally configure `dnsmasq` to pass dhcp requests and responses to and from your home router.

Comment: at the moment, one client is enough for now, thanks

Comment: Added an answer for you to accept :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

- Configure the Raspi with netplan
- Enable ip-forwarding on the Raspi
- Add a NAT rule on the Raspi
- Configure the client with correct IP Address

Details are in the comments.